# What is the maximum temperature to use when cooking with flavor oils?

Tags: flavor, oil, sugar, candy

I'm using standard [LorAnn's flavoring oils](http://shop.lorannoils.com/candy-making/super-strength-flavors), which are supposed to be for 'high temperature' cooking with candy.

So far **275 degrees F** works as far as the flavor goes, but it's *bad* for efficiency, as much of the candy is lost to waste due to cooling and cleaning.

What temperature have you found you can put in oil based flavors into sugar candy without the oil hitting its smoking point?

Comment: Welcome Neceros - There are many types of sugar candy, if you could add your recipe and how you make it, someone here may be able to help.  I really don't understand the "much of the candy is lost to waste due to cooling and cleaning." If you could explain that, it may also help. You can use the "edit" link below your question to make changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge difference in using oil in a pan to cook something and mixing it into a sugar solution for candy-making. I have been using that brand of oils (and others) for decades when making candy and, depending on the end-product (i.e., soft caramel at 246F and a hard-crack candy like toffee at 300F) have never encountered a "smoke-point" problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Every oil, whether flavored or not, has a smoke point. Even the same oils with different branding may have slightly different smoke points.

The only way to really tell what a particular oil's smoke point is, is to heat the oil TO that smoke point and determine the temperature that it is at when it starts to smoke.  You can use a little oil in a small pan to determine that. The easiest way is to use an Infrared Thermometer to get the reading at the exact moment the oil begins to smoke. Do a search for Infrared Thermometer on Amazon to see what's available. Inexpensive.

There is no hard and fast rule for what temperature a particular type of oil's smoke point is. There are only general guides.  Test and record!  Bon Appetit!